# Im only getting "Character (0)" when web-scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

[image]

I cannot get any information from my web-scraping code

I've been trying to solve this issue as at first was getting the error code

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

but I solved that using the lines 4-7. Now I get `charecter (0)`, How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of code. Rather, copy and paste it. You're asking a lot out of the community by asking them to take the time to type it out, when you could just Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V.

Comment: A 403 error means you don't have permission to access the webpage. At a glance, it looks like you wrapped the code in `try()`, so that if there is an error like this, instead of stopping and telling you about the error your code will just continue on silently. But my guess is you still don't have permission to access the webpage. Maybe you need to use an API access token, or log in, or something else.

Comment: it could also be that you've been scraping it a bunch, and the website itself has blocked you. Or maybe they can see your robots.txt and can see you are using a scraping tool and blocked you preemptively